# Using current_user to customize ActionCable channel submittion

Tags: websocket, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm making instant commenting with Rails 5. Using Rails *.js.erb, which is comfortable for this size of project. Also use ActionCable to deliver new comments to users. The thing is that I want ActionCable to send rendered comments/_comment.html.haml directly to client to evaluate this code in browser. In common case it's totally achivable. But in erb template of comment I have to deal with current_user to add delete link if current_user.admin? The problem is when I invoke CommentsChannel.broadcast_to and render _comment.html.haml renderer do not now current_user.

Question is how can I render _comment.html.haml and submit it to each separate subscription defined by current user, using current user from this subscription?

Devise is used for authentication.

**comments/_comment.html.haml**

```
%div[comment]
  .details
    %span.author= comment.user.email
    %span.time= l comment.created_at, format: :short
  = comment.body
  = link_to t('common.reply'), comment, class: 'reply-link'
  = link_to t('common.delete'), comment, method: :delete, remote: true if current_user.admin?
  = render 'comments/form', comment: comment.commentable.comment_threads.build, parent: comment

  - if comment.children.any?
    .child-comments
      = render comment.children.sort_by { |c| c.created_at }.reverse
```

**application_cable/connection.rb**

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    def find_verified_user
      if verified_user = env['warden'].user
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**broadcast_comment_job.rb**

```
class BroadcastCommentJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(comment)
    CommentsChannel.broadcast_to \
      comment.commentable, 
      comment: render_comment(comment)
  end

  private

  def render_comment(comment)
    CommentsController.render(partial: 'comment', locals: { comment: comment })
  end

end
```

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  after_create_commit { BroadcastCommentJob.perform_now(self) }
  ...
end
```

Comment: when I have if verified_user = env['warden'].user , it complains about undefined user?!!!!! and when I run rake middleware, I do not see my warden even though I have warden gem installed? :/

Comment: @KickButtowski do you use Devise or Warden itself? In case of my question it's Devise. I propose you first to check if Warden is in the list of middleware using `rails middleware` command.

Comment: no it is not, and I could not find any good tutorial to help me in proper way. may I ask for your email so we can chat?

Comment: I didn't have a chance to implement custom auth on top of Warden but my friend did and he gave me a link to nice blog post about that. Here you are: https://blog.maestrano.com/rails-api-authentication-with-warden-without-devise/. There is a section that tells how to put warden to the middleware. PS: Don't think that it's good to expose email here but you can contact me at fb.com/abarkov